# Spark with Mesos : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: libsvn_delta-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere

I setup a mesos cluster with 1 master (192.168.2.1), and 2 slaves(192.168.2.2, 192.168.2.3).

And I'm able to access mesos successfully using http://192.168.2.1:5050 and I'm able to see both slaves registered as agents. I then setup spark on these 3 nodes.

I then downloaded libmesos.so  (libmesos-1.8.1.so) from /usr/local/lib and set my local dev machine to

```
export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/mylocallibs/libmesos.so
```

When I try to connect to the master using this SparkConfig

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("mesos://192.168.2.1:5050")
      .setAppName("My app")
      .set("spark.executor.uri", <http url to spark tgz>)
      .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster");
```

I get the following error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: libsvn_delta-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The way I setup spark on these 3 nodes is as follows:

```
# Download spark executable
wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.3/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz -O /opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

# Extract
cd /opt; tar xzf /opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

# Setup link for upgrades
ln -s /opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7 /opt/spark

# Set spark_home
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark

cp $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh.template $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark.env.sh

# Edit spark-env.sh and set variables
vi $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh

export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libmesos.so

export SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI=<http url to spark tgz>

cp $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf.template $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf

# Edit spark defaults and set variables
vi $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf

export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libmesos.so

export SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI=<http url to spark tgz>
```

I tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH  on my local dev machine

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mylocallibs/
```

I downloaded a later version of libsvn_delta-1.so.0 -> libsvn_delta-1.so.1 and renamed it to libsvn_delta-1.so.0 in /mylocallibs just to get going since I was stuck for long.

That only started a chain of other library files being unsatsified.

Have I missed anything obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

library is already loaded by your application and the application tries to load it again, the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` will be thrown by the JVM

> since you are using cluster mode you may need to send the library
>   files through `--files` option before access it.. or **copy lib folder
>   to hdfs and try to access from hdfs in cluster mode** it can read from
>   hdfs.
>   [see this](https://github.com/mesosphere/field-notes/blob/master/docs/spark/spark.md)

In cluster mode the driver runs in the one of the executor node and it cant able to indentify your local path.

to make sure that it was working change deploy-mode to client to see whether its working or not.

or see this, Similar issue was fixed here. have a look at that.

[Installing libcurl4-nss-dev fix the problem.](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-deb-packaging/issues/102)

Comment: Worked! I had to have those jars in a directory and export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH